# How to Erase Hard Drive Mac System (this partition can't be modified/unmount)?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

[image: Volume Erase failed; Volume Erase failed with the error: Couldn't unmoving disk.]

I want to erase a disk (Mac system) to resize OS X Mountain Lion to the max volume but I couldn't resize it nor unmount the other disk.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off your computer and then turn it on again holding the "Option" key on your keyboard.

You'll be showed your boot options. You'll have to boot from a different disk than the one that you are trying to erase. Mac OS X won't erase the disk from which it is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to modify a disk that the system still wants access to, causing it to fail to unmount it.

Boot into the Recovery HD by holding ⌘R on boot, open Disk Utility and try from there.